# How to check if a string is in a specific pattern?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to check a string in a field Fields!group1.Value to see if it is in a specific format as this XX-XXXX-XXXX if it is then i need to make no change in the expression which is this

```
=Fields!group1.Value + " " + Fields!groupDesc1.Value.
```

if not i need to remove the first Fields!group1.Value and keep only Fields!groupDesc1.Value. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps. You may need to amend the [A-Z] for lower case characters or numerals etc

```
=IIF(Fields!group1.Value like "[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]",
Fields!group1.Value + " " + Fields!groupDesc1.Value, 
Fields!groupDesc1.Value)
```

[VB Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/how-to-match-a-string-against-a-pattern)

Comment: it may be of any mixture of numerical and lower or upper for example 07-1324-S000. how do i do that? should i just add something like the below =IIF(Fields!group1.Value like "[A-Z][a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9]-[A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9]A-Z]a-z][0-9]-[A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9][A-Z]a-z][0-9]",
Fields!group1.Value + " " + Fields!groupDesc1.Value, 
Fields!groupDesc1.Value)

Comment: [A-Z] is replaced by [A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: can i do like this %%-%%%%-%%%% or something? using a wild card

Comment: Yes, you could use a '?'. This would allow any character; so the string could have a ^ for example.

Comment: in that case the expression should be =IIF(Fields!group1.Value like "??-????-????",
Fields!group1.Value + " " + Fields!groupDesc1.Value, 
Fields!groupDesc1.Value)